# Racket - How to access superclass method within overridden method in subclass

Tags: methods, overriding, racket, superclass

Let's say I have a class called "bankAccount". This class has a method called "view" with which the amount of money in the account can be accessed.

Let's also say I have a class called "bankAccountPW" which inherits from bankAccount. I would override the 'view' method such that it only returns the amount of money if the correct password is entered. How could I access the base class (bankAccount) 'view' method so I could define the overridden 'view' method in terms of the original 'view' method?

In short, with Racket, how can I access the base class method within the overridden method in a subclass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the super form:

```
#lang racket

(define bankAccount%
  (class object%
    (super-new)
    (define/public (view) 'amount)))

(define bankAccountPW%
  (class bankAccount%
    (super-new)
    (define/override (view) 
      (if #t (super view) 'blocked))))

(send (new bankAccountPW%) view)
=> 'amount
```